# What does it mean Lamport?

Tags: account, staking, fees, balance, lamports

What does it mean Lamport?. How many Lamports is one Solana?. Is it important?. What is Lamport balance?. How to calculate it?. How many Lamports should I have in my account to be estimated rent exempt?.

Answer (score 3):

A Lamport is the smallest unit of currency within Solana.

1 SOL = 1 billion Lamports

Comment: its like wei in eth